# can you tell me what those 2 methods which reads bytes from an Input stream do?

Tags: java, inputstream, b-tree

I am trying to understand an implementation of a b+ Tree. I don't understand what this overloaded method exactly do. Why in the first method having `Inputsteam is` as an argument declare 4 variables which are i1,i2,i3 and i4. In the second method using `ObjectInput in` as an argument, i understand that it returns a byte from 0 to 255, why is result=251? It will be helpful to explain each line and what it do.

**First method:**

```
    public final static int readLuposInt(final InputStream is) throws IOException {
        final int i1 = is.read();
        if (i1 < 0) {
            return i1;
        }
        final int i2 = is.read();
        if (i2 < 0) {
            return i2;
        }
        final int i3 = is.read();
        if (i3 < 0) {
            return i3;
        }
        final int i4 = is.read();
        if (i4 < 0) {
            return i4;
        }
        return (0xFF & i1) | ((0xFF & i2) | ((0xFF & i3) | (0xFF & i4) << 8) << 8) << 8;

}
```

**overloaded method:**

```
public final static int readLuposInt(final ObjectInput in) throws IOException {
        final int i0 = in.read();
        if (i0 <= 251){
            return i0;
        }
        int result = 251;
        int offset = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= i0 - 251; i++) {
            result += in.read() * offset;
            offset <<= 8;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have used a *debugger* to find the following result.

**The first method** reads an 4 byte **integer** from an input stream. It seems to be stored as [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) value.

- the bytes are read in sequentially
- ff any of the bytes is missing, `-1` is returned.
- to return the complete integer, a computation is made by [shifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts) the more significant bytes to the left.

*Example:*

- The number `2293742` represents the hex number `22 FF EE`, which will be stored in reverse order: `0xEE 0xFF 0x22 0x00`
- now the data gets read

  - `i1 = 0xEE`
  - `i2 = 0xFF`
  - `i3 = 0x22`
  - `i4 = 0x00`
- now the return value is computed:

  - `(0xFF & i4) << 8 = (0xFF & 0x00) << 8 = 0x0000`
  - `((0xFF & i3) | (0xFF & i4) << 8) << 8) = ((0x22 | 0x0000) << 8) = (0x0022 << 8)  = 0x002200`
  - `((0xFF & i2) | ((0xFF & i3) | (0xFF & i4) << 8) << 8) << 8 = (0xFF | 0x002200) << 8 = 0x0022FF00`
  - `(0xFF & i1) | ((0xFF & i2) | ((0xFF & i3) | (0xFF & i4) << 8) << 8) << 8 = 0xEE | 0x0022FF00 = 0x0022FFEE`

**The second method** reads unicode characters from the stream, **encoded in an  UTF-8** encoding. Much can be said about unicode and their character encodings, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) how that is working.

Comment: but doesnt `<< 8` means shift 8 bits to the left? And why is there a need to shift there? I dont understant the shifting part can you explain more thanks

Comment: If you look at the definition of the method [int ObjectInput.read()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInput.html)` it says that it only reads a single byte from the input. A java `int` has 4 bytes so you have to split it into 4 parts. To restore the value, you have to shift the parts 1, 2 or 3 `bytes` left and combine them with `|`. `<< 8` shifts one byte to the left.

Comment: By the way, the method has nothing to do with a btree implementation. This methods deal  only with the binary searialization of the tree data.

Comment: I dont understand the connection between the second method and UTF-8 can you explain?

Comment: [Others surely explain better!](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/). Please read this first - the second method just reads unicode codepoints encoded in `utf-8`.